# Multimatch query failure

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Hi Team I am using elasticsearch after a long time and facing some difficulties with multi_match queries.

Essentially my query need to have an exact match on 2 fields and should do a text search on 4 fields.

Here is the exact query that I have prepared which is giving expected results.

```
GET /maintenance_logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "vinNumber.keyword": "DH34ASD7SDFF84742"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "organizationId": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Cabin pressure",
            "fields": [
              "dtcCode",
              "subSystem",
              "maintenanceActivity",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However when I am trying to convert this into Elasticsearch java, I am unable to get data back.

Here is the error:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]

    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/maintenance_logs/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: \"DH34ASD7SDFF84742\"","index_uuid":"VnZg-NkFQmS-nSHbYemZkQ","index":"maintenance_logs"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"maintenance_logs","node":"_XMtzvY5TW-02IijVrR2Ww","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: \"DH34ASD7SDFF84742\"","index_uuid":"VnZg-NkFQmS-nSHbYemZkQ","index":"maintenance_logs","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"DH34ASD7SDFF84742\""}}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1654) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.12.1.jar:7.12.1]
```

Here is the Request:

```
public static SearchRequest buildSearchRequest(final String indexName,
                                                   final ElasticSearchDTO dto,
                                                   final MaintenanceLogsSearchDto maintenanceLogsSearchDto,
                                                   Pageable pageable) {
        try {
            final int page = pageable.getPageNumber();
            final int size =  pageable.getPageSize();
            final int from = page <= 0 ? 0 : pageable.getPageSize();

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();


            final QueryBuilder vinQuery = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("vinNumber.keyword", maintenanceLogsSearchDto.getVinNumber());
            final QueryBuilder orgIdQuery = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("organizationId", maintenanceLogsSearchDto.getVinNumber());

            boolQueryBuilder.must(vinQuery);
            boolQueryBuilder.must(orgIdQuery);

            boolQueryBuilder.minimumShouldMatch(1);

            MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(dto.getSearchTerm(), "dtcCode", "subSystem", "maintenanceActivity", "description");
            multiMatchQueryBuilder.operator(Operator.AND);
            boolQueryBuilder.should(multiMatchQueryBuilder);

            searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

            searchSourceBuilder
                    .from(from)
                    .size(size)
                    .sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("statsDate")
                                  .order(SortOrder.DESC));

            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            return searchRequest;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I would also like to improve my search functionality with another api where I would like to run something like this :

```
"select * from maintenance_logs where subSystem in ["cabin pressure", "Engine, ABS"] or dtcCoe in ["p100", "p200", "p300"]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like issue is with your `vinQuery` as it uses this `DH34ASD7SDFF84742` and it seems you are trying to assign the number to your `vinNumber.keyword` using your Java DTO `maintenanceLogsSearchDto.getVinNumber()`, and once you query it in Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch is not able to convert it to number as it can't be converted to number.

Below log line in your logs give hint about the issue.

> reason":"failed to create query: For input string:
> "DH34ASD7SDFF84742"","index_uuid":"VnZg-NkFQmS-nSHbYemZkQ","index":"maintenance_logs","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For
> input string: "DH34ASD7SDFF84742""}}}]},"status":400}

Comment: How do I run a query from the same table something like this "select * from maintenance_logs where subSystem in ["cabin pressure", "Engine,  ABS"] or dtcCoe in ["p100", "p200", "p300"]"

Comment: Never mind. able to prepare that query im looking for.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMandal glad to hear